# tableView.reloadSections(sectionIndex, with: .none) not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created 3 headerViews and added check box, when select section0 check box i want to expand cells in that section. First time it's creating all sections and when I select check box creating cells, but when i deselect check box it's not hide /removing cells. But i want to remove all cells or hide all cells in section0, section1 etc...

My code is

```
var dateArray:[String]?//Globally
var button:UIButton?//Globally

//Mark - TableView Datasource
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == filterView?.filterTblView {
        if section == 0 {
            print(dateArray?.count ?? 0)
            return dateArray?.count ?? 0
        } else if section == 1 {
            return callTypeArray.count
        } else {
            return departmentArray.count
        }
    }
    else {
        return 0
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
let height:CGFloat!
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            height = 60
        } else {
            height = 40
        }
        //Create header view
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: height))
        let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: headerView.frame.width - 50, height: headerView.frame.height))
        lbl.textAlignment = .left

        lbl.text = sectionsArray[section]
        headerView.addSubview(lbl)

        button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button?.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 30, height: 30)
        button?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onclickDateCheckMark), for: .touchUpInside)
        button?.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "uncheck"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        button?.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "check"), for: UIControl.State.selected)
        headerView.addSubview(button!)
        button?.tag = section

        return headerView
}


@objc func onclickDateCheckMark(sender:UIButton) {
    if sender.tag == 0 {
        if sender.isSelected == true {
            sender.isSelected = false
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                        self.dateArray?.removeAll()
//                    let indexPaths = self.filterView?.filterTblView.indexPathsForVisibleRows
//                    print(indexPaths as Any)
//                    self.filterView?.filterTblView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths!, with: UITableView.RowAnimation.top)

                self.dateArray?.removeAll()
                let sectionIndex = IndexSet(integer: 0)
                   self.filterView?.filterTblView.reloadSections(sectionIndex, with: .none) // or fade, right, left, top, bottom, none, middle, automatic
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.dateArray = ["Today", "Yesterday", "This week", "Last week", "This month", "Last month", "Last 30days"]
//                    print(self.dateArray!)
//                    let indexPaths = self.filterView?.filterTblView.indexPathsForVisibleRows
//                    print(indexPaths as Any)
//                    self.filterView?.filterTblView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths!, with: UITableView.RowAnimation.top)
                let sectionIndex = IndexSet(integer: 0)
                self.filterView?.filterTblView.reloadSections(sectionIndex, with: .none) // or fade, right, left, top, bottom, none, middle, automatic
            }
            sender.isSelected = true
        }
    }

    if sender.tag == 1 {
        if sender.isSelected == true {
            sender.isSelected = false
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.callTypeArray?.removeAll()
                let sectionIndex = IndexSet(integer: 1)
                self.filterView?.filterTblView.reloadSections(sectionIndex, with: .none)
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.callTypeArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
                let sectionIndex = IndexSet(integer: 1)
                self.filterView?.filterTblView.reloadSections(sectionIndex, with: .none)
            }
            sender.isSelected = true
        }
    }

    if sender.tag == 2 {
        if sender.isSelected == true {
            sender.isSelected = false
        } else {
            sender.isSelected = true
        }
    }


}
```

As per my observation actually here in `viewForHeaderInSection section:` **check box button** once again creating when i call `reloadSections`. Thats why it's not entering into if condition `if sender.isSelected == true { }` in `onclickDateCheckMark` it's directly entering false condition.

Comment: On click of header you wanted to show all cell for that section ??... Does one section will be expand at a time ?? And what is `dateArray` ??

Comment: I want to expand one section of cells. But when i select two sections check boxes I want to expand two sections cells.

Comment: @ dahiya_boy, can you please ask me more detailed?

Comment: Don't mind but you won't think millions of conditions gave you an unneccesary headache better you can make extra array to store section index and check for expand collapse from this array.. I prefer this bcz now code is more handy and clean.. rest final calls will be yours.. Right now as I am understanding, You have 3 sections and wanted to expand that section on click and close same on second click. You have 3 different arrays for all these three sections.

Comment: Yes you are right, can you please suggest solution for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create 2 arrays, first for datasource and second for to store selected section index.

   ```
   var arrDataSource : [Any] = [] // your data for all three section, datatype will be as per your requirement
   var arrSelectedIndex : [Int] = [] // initially its empty as when VC loads on section will be expanded, if you want to expand any section initially then fill array with that section.
   ```
2. In **viewDidLoad**,

   ```
   arrDataSource = [arrSection1, arrSection2,arrSection3] // manage your data with single array.. its more dynamic for future purpose
   ```
3. In **numberOfSections** ,

   ```
   func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return arrDataSource.count
   }
   ```
4. Assuming your `viewForHeaderInSection` is working properly, here give button tag (you already done)
5. On `buttonAction`,

   ```
   // First check in section is selected or not.
   if arrSelectedIndex.contains(sender.tag){
       // IF section is selecetd then remove it from arrSelectedIndex
       let aIndex = arrSelectedIndex.firstIndex(of: sender.tag)
       if let aInt = aIndex {
           arrSelectedIndex.remove(at: aInt)
       }
   }
   else{
       // IF section is not selecetd then add it to arrSelectedIndex
       arrSelectedIndex.append(sender.tag)
   }
   // reload tableview
   tblView.reloadSections([sender.tag], with: .automatic)
   ```
6. In **numberOfRowsInSection**,

   ```
   return arrSelectedIndex.contains(section) ? (arrDataSource[section] as AnyObject).count : 0
   ```

**Note:** This is an idea and best approach, if I forget any condition or you have any doubt then pls comment below..

Comment: thank you, your code working good , but how to set checked and unchecked images to button.     button?.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "uncheck"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button?.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "check"), for: UIControl.State.selected)

Comment: @iOS You already set images for button states so below it you can just do `button.isSelected =  arrSelectedIndex.contains(section)`

Comment: Excellent ...Thank you